# Time varying parameter-matrix in deSolve R

Tags: r, if-statement, modeling, ode, differential-equations

I am struggling with this for so long. I have a logistic growth function where the growth parameter
`r` is a matrix. The model is constructed in a way that I have as an output two N the N1 and N2.

I would like to be able to change the r parameter over time. When time < 50 I would like
r = r1 where

```
r1=matrix(c(
  2,3),
  nrow=1, ncol=2
```

When time >= 50 I would like r=r2 where

```
r2=matrix(c(
  1,2),
  nrow=1, ncol=2
```

Here is my function. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
rm(list = ls())      
library(deSolve)

model <- function(time, y, params) {
  with(as.list(c(y,params)),{
    N = y[paste("N",1:2, sep = "")]
    
    dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)
    
    return(list(c(dN)))
  })
}

r=matrix(c(
  4,5),
  nrow=1, ncol=2)

K=100

params <- list(r,K)

y<- c(N1=0.1, N2=0.2)

times <- seq(0,100,1)

out <- ode(y, times, model, params)
plot(out)
```

I would like ideally something like this but it does not work

```
model <- function(time, y, params) {
  with(as.list(c(y,params)),{
    N = y[paste("N",1:2, sep = "")]
    
   r = ifelse(times < 10, matrix(c(1,3),nrow=1, ncol=2),
    ifelse(times > 10, matrix(c(1,4),nrow=1, ncol=2), matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1, ncol=2)))
     
    print(r)
    
    dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)
    
    return(list(c(dN)))
  })
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass a matrix parameter you should pass a list of parameters and you can modify it inside the model when your time limit is exceeded (in the example below you don't even have to pass the `r` matrix to the model function)

```
library(deSolve)

model <- function(time, y, params) {
  with(as.list(c(y,params)),{
    if(time < 3) r = matrix(c(2,3), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
    else r = matrix(c(1,3), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
    N = y[paste("N",1:2, sep = "")]
    
    dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)
    
    return(list(c(dN)))
  })
}

y <- c(N1=0.1, N2=0.2)

params <- list(r = matrix(c(0,0), nrow = 1, ncol = 2), K=100)
times <- seq(0,10,0.1)

out <- ode(y, times, model, params)
plot(out)
```

You can see examples of this for instance with Delay Differential Equations `?dede`

Comment: Thank you, Lewis, that's really helpful. One question If I have three conditions how would it go.. ( if(time >3) .... else if(time=3)....else(time>3) ?

Comment: If its more than one time step, I would recommend a *forcing function* instead of `if` clauses. This was recently discussed on SO several times.

Comment: There are several ways to approach this and @tpetzoldt approach in his answer is quite efficient. I think you could learn a lot from deSolve tutorial where this is presented in (some) details http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/tutorial.pdf, see especially forcings + events section

Answer (score 4):

Here a generic approach that uses an extended version of the `approx` function. Note also some further simplifications of the model function and the additional plot of the parameter values.

**Edit** changed according to the suggestion of Lewis Carter to make the parameter change at t=3, so that the effect can be seen.

```
library(simecol) # contains approxTime, a vector version of approx

model <- function(time, N, params) {
    r <- approxTime(params$signal, time, rule = 2, f=0, method="constant")[-1]
    K <- params$K

    dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)
    
    return(list(c(dN), r))
}

signal <- matrix(
  # time, r[1, 2], 
  c(  0, 2, 3,
      3, 1, 2,
    100, 1, 2), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE
) 

## test of the interpolation
approxTime(signal, c(1, 2.9, 3, 100), rule = 2, f=0, method="constant")

params <- list(signal = signal, K = 100)

y <- c(N1=0.1, N2=0.2)

times <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)

out <- ode(y, times, model, params)
plot(out)
```

[image: State variables and parameters over time]

For a small number of state variables like in the example, separate signals with `approxfun` from package **stats** will look less generic but may be slighlty faster.

As a further improvement, one may consider to replace the "hard" transitions with a more smooth one. This can then directly be formulated as a function without the need of `approx`, `approxfun` or `approxTime`.

**Edit 2:**

Package **simecol** imports **deSolve**, and we need only a small function from it. So instead of loading **simecol** it is also possible to include the `approxTime` function explicitly in the code. The conversion from data frame to matrix improves performance, but a matrix is preferred anyway in such cases.

```
approxTime <- function(x, xout, ...) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {x <- as.matrix(x); wasdf <- TRUE} else wasdf <- FALSE
  if (!is.matrix(x)) stop("x must be a matrix or data frame")
  m <- ncol(x)
  y <- matrix(0, nrow=length(xout), ncol=m)
  y[,1] <- xout
  for (i in 2:m) {
    y[,i] <- as.vector(approx(x[,1], x[,i], xout, ...)$y)
  }
  if (wasdf) y <- as.data.frame(y)
  names(y) <- dimnames(x)[[2]]
  y
}
```

Comment: Thank you @tpetzoldt for your answer. I highly appreciate. Do you know if it would work in the same way (~similar code function) with the deSolve package instead of the simecol or those two packages work together? Sorry I am new on this and I am not entirely sure how it works

Comment: Yes of course, simecol just imports deSolve. The object oriented approach of simecol is not needed here, just the single approxTime function.